# Type error when implementing TryFrom trait

Tags: rust, serde, rust-warp

I am trying to implement `std::convert::TryFrom<OutputMessage>` for `warp::filters::ws::Message` where `OutputMessage` is a simple struct that can be serialized with `serde_json::to_string()`:

```
impl TryFrom<OutputMessage> for Message {
    type Error = ();

    fn try_from(output_message: OutputMessage) -> Result<Self, <Self as TryFrom<Message>>::Error> {
        match serde_json::to_string(&output_message) {
            Ok(output_string) => Ok(Message::text(output_string)),
            Err(err) => {
                return Err(());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following errors for the function signature:

```
method `try_from` has an incompatible type for trait
expected fn pointer `fn(protocol::Output) -> Result<_, ()>`
found fn pointer `fn(protocol::Output) -> Result<_, Infallible>`
```

And this one for the returned `Err(())`:

```
mismatched types
expected enum `Infallible`, found `()`
```

Is there any way to make this implementation work, maybe by changing it's `Error` type? Or is this kind of trait implementation not really possible?

Comment: Try changing the return type to `Result<Self, ()>`. The current return type is wrong because it specifies the `Error` associated type of `TryFrom<Message>`, which is different from the unit type you used for `Error`.

Comment: @user4815162342 but `Error` is set to `()`, I would expect this to still work, no?

Comment: `Self::Error` (i.e. `TryFrom<OutputMessage>::Error`) is indeed `()`, but you were using `TryFrom<Message>::Error`, which is not the same as `TryFrom<OutputMessage>::Error`. As `Self` is `Message`, `TryFrom<Message>` is [automatically implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html#generic-implementations) and returns `Ok(value)`. Also, since `TryFrom<T> for T` cannot fail, the error variant of the conversion result is defined as `Infallible`.